# How to ignore JSON properties similar to @JsonIgnore in Deserialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have a JSON object similar below:

```
[
  {
     "objA": {
       "propA": "AAAA",
       "propB": "BBBB",
       "objB": {
         "objC": {
           "propC": "CCCC",
           "propD": "DDDD"
         }
       },
       "objD": [
         "asa"
       ],
       "propE": "AW",
       "propF": "533",
       "propG": "ABW",
       "propH": "ARU",
       "objE": {
         "objF": {
           "propI": "SASDS",
           "propJ": "54DEFF"
         }
       }
     }
   }
]
```

When I deserialize this JSON into a List, I would like to do for part of this object, for example: I would like to ignore objB, objC, objD, objE and objF.
To do that I has been used the @JsonIgnore annotation. So I did something like that:

```
public class MyClass {

// objects and properties not ignorabled
private ClassA objA;
private String propE;
private String propF;
private String propG;;
private String propH;

// objects ignorabled in deserialization 
@JsonProperty("objB")
@JsonIgnore
private Object objB;

@JsonProperty("objD")
@JsonIgnore
private Object objD;

@JsonProperty("objE")
@JsonIgnore
private Object objE;

/** gets and setters here **/
```

Follow below the piece of code that deserialize my JSON

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(url, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

This code is working. this code is ignoring the objects from JSON, but I believe there are some another way to do that instead of use @JsonIgnore to each object or property in my entity.

Do you know how can I do that better?

Comment: When you have specific properties to exclude during both serialization and deserialization, `@JsonIgnore` is a good choice. However, if you have more dynamic needs, you may implement your own custom deserializer. `class MyDeser extends StdDeserializer<MyClass>`.

Comment: Have you tried using `Transient` keyword? It ignores serialization of keys defined with transient ! Try if it seems a simple solution https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transient-keyword-java/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to avoid using @ notations ?

If not, have you tried using a filter like `@JsonFilter("myFilter")` in Jackson ? As described here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

See also https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsonfilter.htm

So you would have to write:

```
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class MyClass { ... }
```

in your class. Then do something like:

```
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter objBFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
  .serializeAllExcept("objB");
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter objDFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
  .serializeAllExcept("objD");
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter objEFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
  .serializeAllExcept("objE");

FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
  .addFilter("objBFilter", theFilter)
  .addFilter("objDFilter", theFilter)
  .addFilter("objEFilter", theFilter);
```